# how can I add an alpha channel layer behind every photo in a folder?

Tags: command-line, gimp, convert

I have several hundred photos I need to edit. Im using gimp, selecting add alpha channel layer, then selecting the segments to remove. its going to be a long process...and I was hoping I could expedite that process by removing the need for at least 1 step, but so far I have failed.

I have tried:
`convert *.png  -background none -transparent white -flatten $1.png`

and some other commands which seemed to do something, but not in a way I then notice when I go to edit the image in GIMP.
Is there a command that will add an underlying alpha channel to images?
[image: plain bg]
[image: alpha Channel]
I want my images to have no background, with only the alpha channel visible.

Comment: Not a Ubuntu OS question but one of how to use gimp from the way it reads. You may want to start looking here https://www.gimp.org/develop/

Comment: everything after the kernel loading  isnt an os question. its literally all other software. anyway Im not asking a gimp question. gimp might be a solution, or it might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert -alpha deactivate BQf0V.png new2.png
```

[image: alpha layer removed]